# Is there a way to use React-Native with Hyperstack and Ruby?

Tags: react-native, hyperstack

I would like to use React-native with Ruby.

My choice would be Hyperstack, but it is not clear if I can use it only with react and not react-native.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperstack compiles to react with `react-dom`. `react-dom` connects react to the browser DOM. But `react-native` is a replacement of `react-dom` for generating native code primarily for mobile devices. It doesn't know html.